# endpoint URI in express js API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am confused about the URI used to test the output of any API. For example I have a piece of code which writes users into database using POST method.

Usercontroller.js

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    User.create({
            name : req.body.name,
            email : req.body.email,
            password : req.body.password
        },
```

Now I am exporting this router to another file.

```
var Usercontroller = require('./user/UserController.js');
var users = app.use('/users',UserController);
```

Now when I start listening to the port 8082 using this URI :
http://localhost:8082/users I get the expected result.

[image]

I want to make the changes in the request string which is being sent to the router.post.
I tried to change **var users = app.use('/users',UserController);** But that doesn't work. Can anybody explain how URI works in express or node. I am trying to understand this concept!

Comment: So do you want to be able to get access to the string that comes from req.body?

Comment: No req.body will contain the key-value pairs of data which I am displaying in JSON format. I want to change the id passed in the URI for adding the users in database : localhost:port/users is currently what I have but i want to use localhost:port/addusers

Comment: @LovikaJain than you just do : var users = app.use('/addusers',UserController);

Comment: @Burimi I already tried that but that is not working and giving me this as output  :<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot POST /addusers</pre>
    </body>
</html> I am using postman to test the API

Comment: That's strange. Did the server restart when you implemented that change? Are you using nodemon? What Burimi said should work.

Comment: Yeah i restarted the server. even I thought this will do the trick "var users = app.use('/addusers',UserController);" but not working. Can there be some reason for it? I am using Postman.

Comment: It's working. Server wasn't restarting properly. I changed the port to check it and it worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Express adds routes between them.

Your UserController targets the '/' and you add '/users'.

Your API is: POST http://localhost:8082/users/

If you want add an API after '/users' you must declare your router in UserController.

If you want to add GET to this url 'http://localhost:8082/users/foo'. You can add this code to UserController :

`router.get('/foo', function (req, res) {
  // code
}`

Express will add the router together.

Your API will be like that :

- POST http://localhost:8082/users
- GET http://localhost:8082/users/foo

You can use a configurable parameter like that :

`router.delete('/:uuid', function (req, res) {
  // :uuid is in req.params.uuid
}`